# How to do this without multiple inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a group of classes that extend a single abstract class.  A subset of these classes need an identical implelmentation of one of the methods, another subset of the classes needs another implementation of the method, and a third subset requires yet another.  In all there are about ten child classes, but only three possible implementations of one of the methods.  (There are many other methods that the classes implement that have nothing in common.)

I'm trying to figure out the best way to accomplish this.  I think what I would have done in C++ is multiple inheritance: create threee classes that implement only this method, then have the children inherit from the appropriate one of those three classes.

Is there a best practice for doing this in Java?

I was considering an intervening layer of three abstract classes, between the main abstract class and the children.  Each of the the three inheriting from the main abstract class, and implementing the method in question.  Then the children inherit from these threee.  But what I don't like about that is what if another method comes along with a similar "grouping" behaviour, and it does not correspond to the three "middle tier" classes?  That would get ugly

Is any of this making any sense?  I'm writing in a hurry...

**EDIT:** So, 24 hours after asking my question I have received about a half dozen patterns to investigate.  I'm not yet sure that they are all official design pattern names.  But I'm going to look into each and then report back (and choose an answer as correct).  The pattens suggested so far:

```
* Delegation

* Bridge

* Strategy

* Composition

* Decorator (if I was choosing on name alone, I choose this one)
```

I also need to add that the method that is being implemented needs access to nearly all of the private members of the class.  So that will factor large in my choice.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I smell a Strategy pattern here.

You could have that method in the base class delegate to a Strategy that is passed in upon construction. Sub-classes just pass in any one of a set of Strategies as part of their construction. The Strategies themselves could be made available either outside the class, or internally as private classes. This may end up with less classes overall in your hierarchy.

That being said, there are additional smells here, even with my proposed solution. You may want to think at a higher level with interfaces (as mentioned by other solutions) and composition only with no inheritance. Over time I came to the conclusion the inheritance is NOT my friend. Nowadays I avoid it where possible.

Comment: A strategy doesn't have to only apply to 1 method. I can have a strategy that implements multiple methods (if they are at all grouped that way). I can also have multiple Strategy interfaces and implementations for each, then combining them as necessary at construction. Just a thought. Doesn't have to be the best answer. EDIT: This was a response to a comment that was removed *while* I typed. :)

Comment: I like your answer so much I removed mine.  The strategy pattern can also be used a second time if another one of the methods also needs to be shared between classes.

Comment: Sorry, I removed the comment... it was wrong and so was my answer.  But as you can see from my newer comment above, I completely agree with you.

Comment: Ah, was wondering what happened there. Thanks for the clarification (and support!) Toto2.

Comment: For the Strategy pattern I do something like MyX x = new MyXChild(new MyStrategy()); where MyStrategy implements the method in question?  Another question: Am I correct in thinking that with "Composition" the functions are implemented by member variable classes, and thus do not have access to private and protected members of my child class?

Comment: Protected members are accessible to all classes in the same package, so that's one way to solve that, although it's better not to distribute direct access to members too much as that can easily lead to poor encapsulation.  Both private and protected members **can** be accessed by an internal class (i.e. defining a class without the first class).  Private methods cannot be accessed by any other class (except when "cheating" through reflection, bytecode instrumentation, and other advanced features not intended for normal programming use).

Answer (score 6):

Use delegation rather than inheritance. Have all the classes of a same group delegate to a common helper object to implement their method.

Comment: I think the Bridge and Strategy patterns also boil down to delegation. Which of the patterns would be best in your opinion? Or should we do without the patterns here (as far as a helper class is not a pattern all by itself)? I think the asker is now left with multiple answers, all of which are not wrong by themselves...

Comment: The strategy pattern is the one that seems the most appropriate, except the strategy pattern consists in injecting a strategy into a class. In this case, I don't think the classes have to be configurable from the outside. A method must just be externalized from the class. Everything must not have a pattern name, and simple delegation could be sufficient here.

Comment: Agreed. Patterns are nice, but they should not be used in places where they are not *fully* appropriate.

Comment: Thanks JB.  I think I understand what you suggest.  But I want to be sure.  By "delegate" you mean that the the method in the child class makes an explicit call to the helper object's method?  Also, is "delegation" an "official" design pattern name? (And who maintains the registry of official design pattern names?)

Comment: Oh wait a second!  I forgot to mention I need access to almost all of the instance's private members (more than a dozen things functions and variables).  So, in such a pattern, with such a requiremnt, does the child pass it's "this" reference to the delegated method?

Comment: Yes, or it passes a custom object containing just the needed information

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on solving it through inheritance, the [bridge pattern](http://home.earthlink.net/~huston2/dp/bridge.html) from the GoF book could help here (it may or may not be a perfect fit, depending on which domain concerns cause the separation into three implementations). Personally, I'm likely to just put the three method implementations into a helper class and forward the method calls from the classes (what JB Nizet correctly refers to as delegation).

Comment: Thanks for the link I shall read and come back with my questions. Will you still be listening?  I'm new here.  Do comments posted to answers cause some kind of alert to be sent to the answerer?

Comment: Comments to answers trigger a little notification, but if you have subsequent questions it's more in spirit of the website to post them as new ones (while checking for duplicates) instead of requesting follow-up answers on the earlier one. Meta-discussion such as this has [its own sub-site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) and is frowned upon here.

Answer (score 1):

The easy quick fire solution without using inheritance would be to abstract the 3 "common methods" to elsewhere, and then just repeat the method call.

If you want to do it in a nice OO way, then have a look at the decorator pattern which may well help here - create your 3 standard classes that implement your three chosen methods and then "decorate" them with the other classes.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider replacing the abstract class with an interface. I don't know if it is possible
in your case.

Second, you can delegete the functionaity of your "grouping" method to another class (implementator). Create 3 different classes with implementation of the method (or just 3 different methods in some class) and call them from child classes as needed.

So, the "grouping" method will be defined in each child class but it will just explicitly call one of 3 possible implementators.